# crystal reports two date parameters from two tables

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to make a production report from two tables, in both are different dates.
(tables example below)

```
first table (machine ID, production time, date)
-result should be sum of time group by machine ID (parameters - date from - to)

second table (machine ID, repair time, date)
-result should be sum of repair time group by(parameters - date from-to).
```

In report I need to count with sum´s from both tables (for example: `from 1.1.2013 to 10.1.2013`). Problem is that I need to use two different date parameters from both tables but when I use that connection is not working like `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but `INNER JOIN`.(from firts table I need all record and from second only where `id=id`)

Tables examples: [image]

result must be:

machineID | sum of production time | sum of repair time(if there is)         - based on from-to

Comment: Please post your record selection formula and the table joins you're using.

Comment: table joins: `table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on machineID=machineID`

selection criteria: `{spent time} in {?date_from} to {?date_to} and
                    {repair time} in {?date_from} to {?date_to}`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining the tables, try unioning them instead. Something like the following:

```
SELECT machineID, spent_time as time, production_date as date, 'Production' as type
FROM table1
WHERE production_date between {?date_from} and {?date_to}

UNION

SELECT machineID, repair_time as time, repair_date as date, 'Repair' as type
FROM table2
WHERE repair_date between {?date_from} and {?date_to}
```

Then you can easily group by machine and sum all 'Production' rows and all 'Repair' rows separately.

Comment: Thanks, is that way how to do it in crystal report?

Comment: @user2171131 You could either make a view in your database or make a SQL Command in Crystal. Whichever way works.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed two subreports in a single 'main' report.  Define the parameters in the main report, then link them to each subreport.